# No bootable device error message on UEFI after installation

Tags: grub2, uefi, 14.10

I have a new Acer Aspire E13 (ES1-311-P1D5) notebook. I tried to install Ubuntu 14.10 with disabled Secure Boot but enabled UEFI.
After the installation I couldn't bot. I just got "No Bootable Device". I'm not sure what to do except for diabling UEFI.

Is there any way or anything that I need to consider?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could try this similar issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237568

Comment: I'll give it a try. Do you have Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: You should write a proper answer instead of just giving a link to an external site. What if the ext link goes down?

Comment: I activated SecureBoot, added grubx64.efi in my BIOS settings and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In my case some UEFI params needed to be set in the BIOS. I followed these instructions:

https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/

Here is a short description of the steps.

Step 1: Go to BIOS (with F2)

Step 2: Turn ON Secure Boot (You might need to set BIOS password before doing this)

Step 3: Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing: HDD0 -> EFI -> ubuntu -> shimx64.efi

Step 4: Add a description and confirm. Save BIOS settings and reboot.

BTW, later I discovered that when Secure Boot is turned ON that Linux won't recognize WiFi hardware, so I needed to turn it OFF.

Comment: Please be detailed. You may quote other sources but mere posting of links  is not good enough. What if the link goes down. You should add the link as a source instead, Have a great day ahead.

Comment: @SharadGautam The description has been updated with steps. BTW have used the procedure several times in last couple of days

Comment: Saved my hair on an Acer Aspire E 11 :-)

Comment: How do you select a UEFI file?

Answer (score 0):

I have a acer aspire E 15 - E5-573:
After trying different times different bios configurations, ended installing Ubuntu studio 15.04, note version i386 not amd64, with ethernet connection and the bios set to - Legacy.
Ubuntu studio immediatly after disk load made the upgrade to version 16.04.

Another important thing is to check the bios version, if it is 1.25 I read somewhere that it has a bug that doesn´t lets install Linux. Well I installed windows 10 to make a bios update to version 1.37. Then made those bios tests until - bios: **Legacy**, iso: **i386** not amd64.

Good luck