# Cant boot - no bootable device found

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have installed Ubuntu on an Acer laptop, and after working fine for 5 months, today a have boot problems: no bootable device

I checked the BIOS and i can see the hard drive, but the hard drive is not listed when i boot ubuntu from a live usb. I also try the ubuntu boot repair and the results are here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10997880

Any suggestions or advices are really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>,    ?</sup>
If your BIOS saw the hard drive, you have to restore the Master Boot Record.
Do you have access to a console?

if yes, run this:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
```

if it doesn't help run this:

```
chkdsk : /f /r
```

And you can use Partition Magic app, boot this from USB and restore MBR.

Maybe these will help you:

<sub>* [No bootable device error message on UEFI after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546909/no-bootable-device-error-message-on-uefi-after-installation)

* http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1820247

* http://geek.co.il/2013/04/22/how-to-fix-no-bootable-device-after-ubuntu-installation</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont know why but today the laptop magically boots again. I think something is phisically wrong with the hard drive. Inmediatly backed up all my important files. Not sure if its safe to keep using this hard drive, i'll run all test, search for bad sectors, etc. Once again, thanks for the answer.